# I cannot get my simulator to work: Error running pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, podfile

When I try to run my Flutter app on my iPhone 14 Pro Max simulator, I get the following error message:

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

   
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

my Podfile looks like this:

```
 platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I suspect that there's something wrong with my Podfile, and I should mention that I have an M1 processor. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 7):

I removed

```
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
```

from PodFile and I can run the app. It seems RunnerTests is for unit tests or integration tests and have to be set up separately.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Was the project that gave you this issue an older one? Perhaps `RunnerTests` was only added later on.